# Why doesn't the ##* outline work with Python?

Tags: python, outline-mode

I have the following configuration for outlines in my `init.el` file:

```el
(defvar my-outline-regexp-alist
  '((emacs-lisp-mode . "\\s-*;;\\*+")
    (js2-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (web-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (java-mode       . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (c-mode          . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (python-mode     . "\\s-*##\\*+")
    (sh-mode         . "\\s-*##\\*+")))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)

(defun my-toggle-outline ()
  "Toggle outline visibility using `outline-toggle-children'."
  (interactive)
  (if (outline-on-heading-p t)
      (outline-toggle-children)
    (indent-for-tab-command)))

(defun my-setup-outline-mode ()
  (let ((regexp (cdr (assoc major-mode my-outline-regexp-alist))))
    (when regexp
      (setq-local outline-regexp regexp)
      (outline-minor-mode 1)
      (evil-define-key 'normal outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-toggle-outline))))
```

It works perfectly fine for all programming languages except for Python (I can toggle the outlines with the TAB key in evil mode). The idea is to use the outline with a comment and `*` after it, this way I have something similar to `org-mode` in my programming language files. So, it works as the following:

1. In `emacs-lisp-mode` I can use `;;*` to create the first layer of the outline, `;;**` to create the second layer of it and so on... It also accepts any space before it.
2. In `js2-mode` I can use `//*` for the first layer and so on.
3. In `sh-mode` I can use `##*` for the first layer and so on.

Well, even though it works perfectly fine in any programming language that I've tried, it doesn't work at all in `python-mode`. I know that if I use the expression:

`(python-mode     . "\\s-*\\(def\\|class\\)\\b")`

it will fold my outlines fine in `class` and `def` keywords... But I'd like to fold Python code using comments like `##*` or `#*`.

What am I getting wrong? It doesn't make sense that it works fine in `sh-mode` and it doesn't work for `python-mode`. Is there any extra detail I should know while creating outlines in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-mode` sets `outline-heading-end-regexp` to `":[^\n]*\n"` which makes the heading stretch to the next colon.

`(setq-local outline-heading-end-regexp "\n")`  should make the heading you are looking for.

`python-mode` also sets `outline-level` to

```el
(lambda ()
                "`outline-level' function for Python mode."
                (1+ (/ (current-indentation) python-indent-offset)))
```

I believe you want the `outline-level` to be based on the length of the regexp match.

Modifying the `outline-level` found in outline.el yields:

```el
(defun my-python-outline-level ()
  (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0)))
```

and then

```el
(setq-local outline-level #'my-python-outline-level)
```

---

A complete functional solution that allows you to outline Python and other languages would be:

```el
(defvar my-outline-regexp-alist
  '((emacs-lisp-mode . "\\s-*;;\\*+")
    (js2-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (web-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (java-mode       . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (c-mode          . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (python-mode     . "\\s-*##\\*+")
    (sh-mode         . "\\s-*##\\*+")))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my-setup-outline-mode)

(defun my-toggle-outline ()
  "Toggle outline visibility using `outline-toggle-children'."
  (interactive)
  (if (outline-on-heading-p t)
      (outline-toggle-children)
    (indent-for-tab-command)))

(defun my-python-outline-level ()
  (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0)))

(defun my-setup-outline-mode ()
  (let ((regexp (cdr (assoc major-mode my-outline-regexp-alist))))
    (when regexp
      (setq-local outline-regexp regexp)
      (outline-minor-mode 1)
      (evil-define-key 'normal outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-toggle-outline)
      (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
        (setq-local outline-heading-end-regexp "\n")
        (setq-local outline-level #'my-python-outline-level)))))
```