# org-content function equivalent for using in the outline-minor-mode

Tags: outline-mode

I know I can use the function `org-content` to fold all my outlines to specific levels when I'm in `org-mode`. That means:

1. Using `(org-content 1)` will fold all my org outlines to the first level
2. Using `(org-content 2)` will fold all my org outlines until the second level
3. Using `(org-content 3)` will fold all my org outlines until the third level

That works fine. However, I want to do exactly the same thing in the `outline-minor-mode` instead of the `org-mode`. My outlines are defined as:

```el
(defvar my-outline-regexp-alist
  '((emacs-lisp-mode . "\\s-*;;\\*+")
    (js2-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (web-mode        . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (java-mode       . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (c-mode          . "\\s-*//\\*+")
    (python-mode     . "\\s-*##\\*+")
    (sh-mode         . "\\s-*##\\*+")))
```

The complete configuration can be found on [this other emacs exchange answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77056/39141). I haven't found any built-in outline function that substitutes the function `org-content`. The function `outline-hide-sublevels` is apparently the equivalent to the `org-content`, but if I execute `(outline-hide-sublevels 1)` for example it doesn't work as the `(org-content 1)` does in `org-mode`.

Is there any built-in function I can use in `outline-minor-mode` that will work as the `org-content` function? If not, is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is provided by `outline-hide-sublevels` but you have to fix your outline-regexp. Try e.g. with an `emacs-lisp-mode` `outline-regexp` of `;;;*`.

Comment: That's not working in my case... I said in my question that I've tried using `(outline-hide-sublevels 1)` but it doesn't work at all... I only see `...` at my first outline when I use it, and even the headings of my outlines are not shown. I'm not sure if it's a conflict with the way I'm configuring my outlines. But the function `outline-hide-sublevels` is not doing what it should be doing in my case.

Comment: Ah sorry, I notice now that I did not read that part. Anyway, when I replace my emacs-lisp `outline-regexp` with the version from your alist, indeed the function doesn't work. Try again with the following emacs-lisp outline-regexp `;;;;*` (or with the default emacs-lisp outline-regexp when starting from emacs -q). I guess, similarly, your other 'outline-regexp' break the `outline-hide-sublevels` functionality.