# outline-minor-mode works for Haskell but not Python

Tags: outline-mode, haskell-mode, python-mode

I can use `outline-minor-mode` to fold Haddock-style headings in Haskell code. For instance, consider the following file:

```haskell
-- (haskell-mode)
-- (outline-minor-mode)
-- (setq-local outline-regexp "-- [*]+")

-- * 1
-- ** 11
let this_haskell_variable = 3
-- ** 12
-- * 2
let another_haskell_variable = 4
```

After evaluating the elisp code at the top of the file and then moving point to the first heading (the line that says "-- * 1"), running `M-x outline-cycle` cycles between different folding states of the subtree below that heading.

Now consider a nearly-identical Python file:

```python
## (python-mode)
## (outline-minor-mode)
## (setq-local outline-regexp "## [*]+")

## * 1
## ** 11
this_python_variable = 3
## ** 12
## * 2
another_python_variable = 4
```

In this case, after evaluating the elisp code at the top and moving the point to the first heading, `M-x outline-cycle` has no visible effect.

(Side note: It would be more idiomatic to use one # instead of two in the Python code. I tried that, and got the same result. But for demonstration purpposes, I have made the two files as similar as possible.)

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior, although I don't know what causes it.

Comment: It looks like it's because `python-mode` already defines `outline-mode` variables. I don't entirely understand it but much or all of this [solution to someone else's problem](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77056/20176) may apply to mine.

Comment: Yes, that looks very plausible.

Comment: This question has a voted answer here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77048/why-doesnt-the-outline-work-with-python. Attn. moderators, this question could be marked as duplicate of that in link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the ##\* outline work with Python?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77048/why-doesnt-the-outline-work-with-python)